# Keeping page in one place while changing images or reloading page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, gallery

I've checked this site for the same kind of questions but I'm not looking to change the image on this project without the page reloading - it needs to reload. Although when I do click the `next` or `previous` buttons the page jumps right to the top again as it should do, is there a way to combat that so that when the user clicks the next image the page reloads with the image on screen rather than the user having to scroll down every time? Here is my script:

```
$albumName = "Our Gallery"; // Name your album!

/*
 * Installation:
 * 1.) Place your photos into the images directory.
 *      - Photos will be displayed in alphabetical order.
 * 2.) Rename the "basic-php-photo-album" folder to anything you wish.
 *      - Example: paris-photo-album
 * 3.) Upload the renamed folder and all of its contents to your server.
 *      
 * That's it! Make multiple albums by repeating the above 3 steps.
 */

/*
 * You shouldn't need to change anything beyond this.
 *
 */

$p = $_GET['p'];
if ($handle = opendir("uploads")) {
    $i = 1;
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $img[$i] = $file;
            if ($p == $img[$i]) {
                $ci = $i;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    $ti = $i - 1;
    $pi = $ci - 1;
    if ($p == "") {
        $ni = $ci + 2;
    } else {
        $ni = $ci + 1;
    }
    $prevNext = "";
    if ($pi > 0) {
        $piFile = $img[$pi];
        $prevNext .= "<a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?p=" . $piFile . "\" title=\"Previous image\">Previous &#171</a>";
    } else {
        $prevNext .= "&#171;";
    }
    $prevNext .= " | ";
    if ($ni <= $ti) {
        $niFile = $img[$ni];
        $prevNext .= "<a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?p=" . $niFile . "\" title=\"Next image\">&#187 Next</a>";
    } else {
        $prevNext .= "&#187;";
    }
    if ($p == "") {
        $p = $img[1];
    }
}
?> 

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dave's Caravan Lettings</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Hire our Deluxe Plus Caravan based in Sandy Bay, Exmouth for an easy, great priced family holiday! Comes complete with all required facilities as standard!">
<meta name="keywords" content="Haven,Holidays,Sandy,Bay,Devon,Cliffs,Exmouth,Beach,Caravan,Hire,Rental,Rent,Cheap,Holiday,Family,Entertainment,Daves,Letting,Lettings,Fun,Best,Stay,Nights,Price,Buy">
<meta name="author" content="BaseEnterprises WebDesign">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
    <style type="text/css">

        td, select, input {
            font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
        }


        .hRule {
            border-top: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
            margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
        }

        img {
            border: 1px solid #333333;
        }

        .nextPrevious {
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #cdcdcd;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }

        a, a:visited {
            color: #cc0000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a:active, a:hover {
            color: #cc0000;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rochester' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="header-bg">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="index.html">Dave's Caravan Lettings</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bot">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="availability.php">Availability</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="wrap">
            <span class="banner-img">
                <img src="images/banner2.jpg" alt=""/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
 <div class="wrap">
     <div class="content-bot">
                <h3><?php echo $albumName; ?></h3>
                <p>Images sent to us by previous holiday makers staying in our Caravan... See what it's like yourself by browsing the images below...</p><br></br>
                <div class="inner-top">
                    <div class="section group" align="center">



                <div class="hRule"></div>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr align="center">
        <td class="nextPrevious"><?php echo $prevNext; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $p; ?>" alt="<?php echo $$albumName; ?>" border="0" height="300px" width="400px"></td>
    </tr>
</table>






            </div>
            </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: There are multiple options to achieve this. Assign id to HTML element and send it in url, like ?p=filename#yourhtmldivcontainingimage or Simply use iFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to scroll right to the bottom automatically, depending on how large your images are - you could use something like this:

```
$(".section group").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
  return false;
```

And then add this to your page:

```
<div class="section group" align="center" style="overflow-y: scroll;height:520px;width:520px 240px">
```

Then all you would do is fiddle around with the width and height attributes until they match your design.

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but why is this the accepted answer? I don't really want to go into numerating all the things that trouble me with the given code snippets...

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript

get the current scroll with:
`document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop`
And add that to the reloaded page so it scrolls to the same position as it was.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to pass the scroll position over to the next page, and restore that setting with javascript. My example includes jQuery to make life easier. Plain Javascript would probably involve some cross browser compatibility hassle.

You could insert this *(tested)* example code in your `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // set scroll position to the previous state, only if it was given
        <?php if( isset($_GET['scrollTop']) ) {
           echo "$('body').scrollTop(" . $_GET['scrollTop'] . ");";
        } ?>
        // append current scroll position parameter to the link
        $('.nextPrevious').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.location.href = $(this).attr('href') + '&scrollTop=' + $('body').scrollTop();
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you are already using jQuery in your page you don't need to include it again, of course.